# tkinter- not able to pass strings

Tags: python, tkinter

```py
from tkinter import *

import pickle

root= Tk()


label1= Label(root, text='''
lolipop)''')
label1.pack()


def login(usr,psd):
    
  
    file = open("password.dat","rb")
    realcred=pickle.load(file)
    
    if usr in realcred:
        if realcred.get(usr)==psd:
            loginsucc=Label(root,text="YOU HAVE SUCCESSFULLY LOGGED IN")
            lodinsucc.pack()
        
        else:
            loginfail=Label(root,text="INCORRECT PASSWORD")
            loginfail.pack()
            
    else:       
        wrongusr=Label(root,text="USERNAME DEOES NOT EXIST!")
        wrongusr.pack()
        

def loginscreen():
    
    
    loginbutton.configure(state=DISABLED)
    
    loginlabel=Label(root,text="ENTER USERNAME AND PASSWORD BELOW-->")
    loginlabel.pack()
    
    username=Entry(root,width=50,bg="yellow",borderwidth=5) 
    username.pack()
    
    password=Entry(root,width=50,bg="yellow",borderwidth=5) 
    password.pack()
    
    usr=username.get()
    psd=password.get()
    
    submitbotton=Button(root,text="CLICK HERE TO SUBMIT",command=lambda: login(usr,psd))
    submitbotton.pack()
    

        
    
    

loginbutton=Button(root,text="-->>CLICK HERE TO LOGIN<<--",padx=50,pady=15,command=loginscreen)
loginbutton.pack()
```

password.dat is a file which contains dictionary with username as key and password as value(both strings).im not able to pass the username and password from tkinter entries
because it shows FALSE in "usr in realcred" even though i typed correct.

Comment: In you own words, where the code says `if usr in realcred:`: what do you expect `usr` to contain? What *type* is that value? What do you expect `realcred` to be? What *type* is that value? *How did you verify* these things?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. You need to try to [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) the code and diagnose the problem.

Comment: Try to follow through the logic of your code step by step. At what point in the process do the contents of the text entry fields get recorded in `usr` and `psd`?

Comment: i expect usr to be a atring and contain the username i want to pass.In the statement. realcred is a dictionary i loaded from a binary file in which is in the form {"usernmae":"password"} (both key and value are strings.).First i run loginscreen() function use entry function to receive input from user and use get() function to put the values into usr and psd .

Comment: in the statement "if usr in realcred", i expect it to come True. but it is showing false.btw i use submitbotton to pass the values usr and psd to login() function

Comment: Okay. So. when you click the submit button, you want the `login` function to use the text that is in the `username` and `password` text fields *at that time*, right? But... when does the `usr=username.get()` and `psd=password.get()` part happen? Was the text typed in yet? Do you see the problem now?

Comment: i understand. Thank you very much